# Facebook iFrame app - How to use fbml/xfbml

Tags: facebook, fbml, xfbml

I'm trying to use xfbml within my facebook app (iframe) but it somehow doesn't show up.
I copied this tag into one of the pages...

```
<fb:share-button href="http://apps.facebook.com/example" type="box_count"></fb:share-button>
```

..but as i said it doesn't show up.

Any idea how that works?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you loading the Facebook Connect javascript libraries? fbml is not going to render without Facebook's javascript parsing it.

Comment: totally overlooked this article... works like a charm now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial (its German) but there are Code-Snippets:
http://www.my-digital-home.com/2010/06/09/facebook-xfbml-leicht-gemacht/

Answer (score 0):

how and where we must load the Facebook Connect javascript libraries?